# Wordpress get_posts() category parameter problems

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm showing a grid of posts with get_posts() function and trying to control category parameter value from a custom field.

my code works if category parameter gets value from echo function for example:

```
$args = array( 
'numberposts' => 6,
'category'         => '<?php echo "25";?>'
,);
```

but it doesn't when I do something like

```
$catid = get_field( "id_of_product_category" );
$args = array( 
'numberposts' => 6,
'category'         => '<?php echo $catid;?>'
,);
```

at the same time I'am able to

```
echo $catid;
```

on the page and it does show correct value set in custom field.

Why I can't get it to work to change category parameter then?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the quotes around '<?php echo $catid;?>'? It is a variable, not a string.

Comment: `$args = array( 
'numberposts' => 6,
'category'         => get_field( "id_of_product_category" )
,);`

Comment: No, it won't work like that - syntax error. You nee quotes. The first example works ok with quotes. It just doesn't put the value of variable there where at the same time I'm able to print,echo this variable.

Comment: Did you try not having the php around it and just echo $catid? You are already using php so no need for those.

Comment: We were writing at the same time. the code you posted above still does nothing.

Comment: Why are you redeclaring that you are using php with <?php around your variable? You are inside $args which is already php.

Comment: You have a trailing comma in your $args array btw. That would cause a syntax error.

Comment: Instead of an example, post your code, when i read this i though you are trying to put your code in a js file. You need to verify that your PHP tags are correctly open ans closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that your get_field() is missing a second parameter. If you don't specify the specific id of the post that has a field with that name, it will most likely default to the current post's value if it exists. So you basically need to loop through your get_posts() to get the current post that would have the value you are seeking, then do the functionality you are looking for. Exposing more of your could would be helpful.

```
// Get your custom field from ACF based on field name and the ID of the post
$catid = get_field( "id_of_product_category", $post->ID );

$args = array( 
'numberposts' => 6,
'category'    => $catid
);
```

Comment: still doesn't work, for some reason it does not put right value in there

Comment: can you var_dump your $args and then die(); and show me what's there?

Comment: `var_dump($args); die();`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: var_dump returns:

Comment: array(2) { ["numberposts"]=> int(6) ["category"]=> string(1) "1" }   
1 is the correct category ID I set in my custom field for this post, yet posts showed in the grid are the ones from category set previously manually at 'category'  => 64

Comment: ok works perfect! ignore above comments, there was something in code I changed yesterday which shouldn't be there, now the above code works

Comment: Awesome @ArturBrowarski, glad I could help. My answer makes sense and everything to you right? If you need more clarification I'd be happy to elaborate further.